# Using GPU after setting up Discrete Device Assignment (DDA) with Windows 10 VM

Tags: virtual-machine, gpu, discrete-graphics

I have setup a VM to allow it to use a graphics card through DDA per these instructions (and much other investigation):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/deploy/deploying-graphics-devices-using-dda

I can login to VM and have assigned it an Nvidia Quadro graphics card.

However, where is the viewport acceleration occurring?

- Through the Hypervisor viewer?
- Remote desktop? Only through the video card output?
- Or all of the above?

I can't find a definitive answer for this anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is being accelerated through Remote Desktop for certain. I have used Performance Monitor and watched an **NVIDIA GPU** metric and observed the GPU usage, memory, etc.

However, logging in through Hypervisor viewer did not, in my case, trigger use of the GPU. The **NVIDIA GPU** metrics were all 0. Not sure why this is.

However, when I

1. Logged in with RDP, observed GPU usage as expected, closed the
   window (but did not log out of the session)
2. Later connected with the same login account and Hypervisor, I
   observed the **NVIDIA GPU** metric and the GPU was still being used

RDP must trigger GPU usage in some way that Hypervisor viewer does not.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to VM via Hyper-V manager uses Remote Desktop.
After installation GPU driver in guest OS you can see GPU display adapter in Device manger.
Also you can see monitor that uses Hyper-V display adapter.
To `Enable GPU Rendering for Microsoft Remote Desktop` try this [article](https://knowledge.civilgeo.com/knowledge-base/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-microsoft-remote-desktop/). (in guest OS)

Before implementing steps from this article I was not able to launch NVidia Control panel: it said that NVidia GPU is not connected to active monitor.
After implementing these steps I launched NVidia Control panel.
Also I launched Furmark and ran test for my GPU with good results.